# BIt Locker missing from Control Panel WIndows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, windows, bitlocker, control-panel

I just formatted my laptop and installed Windows 7 ultimate but Bit locker Encryption is missing from control panel and also typing bit locker in start menu doesn't help.
Is there any way I can download bit locker manually as my windows update also not working.

I got the installed Windows from an institution that has only limited services associated like internet explorer is also excluded etc. and I want to use the same Windows 7.

**EDIT**
Please see the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bit locker won't become available until you activate your copy of Windows. The feature remains "locked" until activation has been completed and you have rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

First maybe do try and activate Windows as [Andrew](https://superuser.com/users/396484/andrew) suggested.

Another option is try running this command from the command prompt:

> control /name Microsoft.BitLockerDriveEncryption

If it doesn't open BitLocker Drive Encryption, try running this command from an **elevated** command prompt (run as administrator):

> manage-bde -status

You should get something like this:
[image: BitLocker Drive Encryption tool in the Command prompt]

- The manage-bde command is one of the commands of the BitLocker Drive Encryption tool in the Command prompt. You can read more about them at: [BitLocker Command-line Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706522(WS.10).aspx)
- If you're not sure how to start an elevated command prompt please read [Elevated Command Prompt](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/783-elevated-command-prompt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an essential service is disabled/incorrectly working. Try the following

Use the RUN command (CTRL+R) to go to
`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\services.lnk`
**or**
`services.msc`

Check to see if "Shell Hardware Detection" service working.

1. If the 'Status' column shows '**Running**', right click on the service and select 'Restart' to restart the service.
2. If the 'Status' column is **blank**, then the service is not started or the service is disabled.

   - Right clicking on the service and select '**Start**'.
   - If '**Start**' option is greyed out, the service is disabled. Select '**Properties**' and change the Startup type to `Manual` or `Automatic`. (see the screenshot below) Click on **OK**, and you should now be able to right click and **Start** the service.

[image: Change startup type to Manual or Automatic]

Check to see if **BitLocker Drive Encryption** is now available in Control Panel or type `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\BitLocker Drive Encryption` in address bar of windows explorer to go to it directly.

Check My Computer / This PC to see if the BitLocker encrypted drive is not accessible and the drive icon has changed from generic to drive locked icon.

**Source**: [Microsoft Community Q&A](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/bitlocker-option-missing-from-control-panel/f31e4a40-61b5-4c6a-84cf-f95abf7fc7cf)